# Sending push notification to pushwoosh server from my website

Tags: cordova, pushwoosh

I'm working on a cross platform phonegap project for ios, androids, blackberry and windows and i want this applications to be receiving updates from my website (php). I don't want to be sending on the pushwoosh site. I will be glad if you can help me understand the concept. I know how to store the device tokens on my database along side the device brand (ios, androids, bb etc).

But how will i send payloads to pushwoosh server? can i send it to all the platform at once or i will have to handle for individual platform seperately. Please i your assistance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Pushwoosh Remote API, there is a PHP sample in the guide:

http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/pushwoosh-push-notification-remote-api/#PushserviceAPI-PHPSample

With this you can send to all platform at once, or separately, if you want to.

Comment: plz tell me on thing, is it free or a paying service to send a notification from  a website using the api???

Comment: Yes it's free. You can check the prices here: https://www.pushwoosh.com/pricing/. When you open the link you will see which features are available when you have the free version or any other version.